# Can you see why this if statement is not working correctly?

Tags: java

When i run this the if statement always returns false and thus doesn't run the two lines i have there.  You can see in the above line i checked if the words are actually the same and they are identical. So is there something here that i am completely oblivious to or am i just screwed? If it matters i am using eclipse.

```
boolean wordHasElement = false;
for (int firstdimension = 0; firstdimension <= wordnumber-1; firstdimension++){
    System.out.println("-"+ words[firstdimension][0] + "-" + linewords[linewordnumber]  + "-");
    if (words[firstdimension][0] == linewords[linewordnumber] ){
        System.out.println("Worked");
        wordHasElement = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix the amount of whitespace!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> if (words[firstdimension][0] == linewords[linewordnumber] ){

Should be replaced with

```
if (words[firstdimension][0].equals(linewords[linewordnumber] ){
```

- == checks to see if one object is the same as another, which you really aren't interested in.
- `equals(...)` checks if the two Strings hold the same string -- the same letters in the same order -- and that's what matters. Or you could use `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` if case doesn't matter.

Comment: I combined our two answers and just deleted mine, if that's OK. 1+.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks :) So what exactly was it that i was checking for before? (Just trying to fully understand)

Comment: You code as it appears in the question checks to see if two objects reside in the same location in memory. The code in the answer here checks to see if two strings have the same text.